# NoReverseMatch error from Python Tutorial

Tags: python-3.7, django-2.2

Django Tutorial part 4 I am getting a NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/

- NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/
  Reverse for 'polls.index' not found. 'polls.index' is not a valid view
- In template /var/www/html/django_app/polls/templates/polls/detail.html, error at line 5
- Reverse for 'polls.index' not found. 'polls.index' is not a valid view function or pattern name...

I have looked up and researched this question on here for a while and am hitting a wall.  There are many references to the problem but none that match the problem I am seeing and the state of my current code.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

detail.py

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls.vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }</label><br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'polls/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    # Always return and HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealin
    # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
    # user hits the Back button.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

I can clearly see what it saying the problem is but I can't seem to determine what is causing it.

Any extra eyes would help and be greatly appreciated!

Comment: syntax should be `polls:index` in the templates

Comment: I tried that earlier for both polls.index and polls:index

Error during template rendering
In template /var/www/html/django_app/polls/templates/polls/detail.html, error at line 5

Reverse for 'polls.index' not found. 'polls.index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.