# Django Polls Project: Reverse for 'polls.index' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to finish my Django Polls Project from the Django Documentation but I ran into the "Reverse for 'polls.index' not found. 'polls.index' is not a valid view function or pattern name." error.

The full error details can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3SL5.png)

The following are my files.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Pollster {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block content %} 
    <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Poll Questions</h1>
    {% if latest_question_list %}
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="lead">{{ question.question_text}}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}" class="btb btn-primary btn-sm">Vote Now</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'polls:results' question.id %}" class="btb btn-secondary btn-sm">Results</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls available</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

mysite.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls.urls

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views  #from ALL import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Question, Choice

# Get questions and display them

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


# Show specific question and choices 
def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

# Get question and display results

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

# Vote for a question choice
def vote(request, question_id):
    # print (request.POST['choice'])
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}" class="btb btb-secondary btn-sm mb-3">Back To Polls</a>
<h1 class="text-center mb-3">{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}
<p class="alert alert-danger">   
    <strong>{{ error_message }}</strong>
</p>

{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method ="post">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" name="choice" class="form-check-input" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value = "{{ choice.id }}"/>
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">
            {{ choice.choice_text }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value ="Vote" class ="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block mt-4" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I am new to Django and I would like to learn methods to find out where the errors could be originating from. I checked the code in reference with this [finished project](https://github.com/bradtraversy/pollster_django_crash/tree/master/pollster/polls) from the channel I'm watching but couldn't find the error I made.

Where could the error in my code be?

I researched and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896605/noreversematch-error-from-python-tutorial) stackoverflow question might be the same as mine but was not solved as well.

Here is my [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/933rB.png)

I am also new to python for web development so any tips on how I could study this would be helpful. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Sorry if I missed it, but where are you calling ```{% url 'polls:index' %}```? The error message says it is in line 12 where you call ```{% block title%}```. Are you over riding {%block title%} in part of your code you didn't show?

Comment: Also, can you post your polls.views? It sounds like it can't find index

Comment: have you added 'polls' app in installed apps?

Comment: I have inserted my detail.html file where {% url 'polls:index' %} is being called. I also edited and inserted my polls.views file. How can I trace where the error is? Is it an error in syntax?

Comment: You have to import the reverse function in your `urls.py`. `from django.urls import reverse`, currently you imported it in your polls.views.py

Comment: @Danizavtz I tried this and it still resulted in the same error. I checked the github repository to compare how we imported in views.py,  polls.urls and mysite.urls and all seems to be correct. I will add my file structure.

Comment: There is something weird about the error message. When I say "{% url myapp:fakeurl %}" on my project I get the error "fakeurl" not fount, not myapp.fakeurl. Also, it is pointing you to line 12 of base.html.  Well I'm perplexed, make sure you're using django 2.2. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @sintribu I'll try redoing the project and update this question with the solution once I figure out what went wrong.